# How to add multiple products to cart by clicking their checkboxes within a table in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new in this community, I will appreciate your help with this topic.

I'm designing a website with Wordpress and Woocommerce and just installed Woo Product Table plugin to show products on a table and add multiple products to cart. At the moment I have to check the products I want  and then click a button to add them to cart, but the feature I want to add is just to click the checkboxes and automatically add them to the cart without clicking the other button I mentioned. I asked the plugin developers and told me that this feature could be added using hooks (actions and filters) but the documentation they give is not enough. I haven´t used hooks before but found Code Snippets plugin to try some examples of these hooks.

I use this example to see if the hooks are working and they do:

```
if( !function_exists( 'codeastrology_wpto_searchbox_taxonomy_name' ) ){

function codeastrology_wpto_searchbox_taxonomy_name( $taxonomy_name, $taxonomy_keyword){
    if( $taxonomy_keyword == "product_cat"){
        $taxonomy_name = "Business area ";
    }
    if( $taxonomy_keyword == "product_tag"){
        $taxonomy_name = "Filter by Tag";
    }
    return $taxonomy_name;
}
}
 add_filter( 'wpto_searchbox_taxonomy_name', 'codeastrology_wpto_searchbox_taxonomy_name', 10,2 );
```

This is the list of actions and filters they have:
https://wooproducttable.com/api-list/

Any suggestion of how can I add this feature using Code Snippets?

Comment: Not sure why they are referring you to the server-side hooks; first and foremost I would think this requires modification of the client-side scripting logic - a `change` event handler added to those checkboxes, and then in the callback function the appropriate AJAX request to add/remove the product should be made.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CBroe , I will look for that client-side scripting.